# Seeking examples of 3rd party native iphone apps that can be launched from mobile safari

Tags: iphone

I am looking for a particular example of a native 3rd party iphone app that can be launched from within mobile safari. While I read here that this is feasible using a custom URL scheme, I could not find any evidence for that online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear as to what you want. If you're looking for a list of supported custom URL schemes, there's no official list. 
There are user maintained lists though:

Check this: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

And this: http://www.handleopenurl.com/scheme